# How do I fetch multiple hash values at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, destructuring

What is a shorter version of this?:

```
from = hash.fetch(:from)
to = hash.fetch(:to)
name = hash.fetch(:name)
# etc
```

Note the `fetch`, I want to raise an error if the key doesn't exist.

There must be shorter version of it, like:

```
from, to, name = hash.fetch(:from, :to, :name) # <-- imaginary won't work
```

It is OK to use ActiveSupport if required.

Comment: One important and unasked question is. What for do you want to reassign values from hash to vars?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel I cannot parse your comment above.

Comment: Why do you want to do `from = hash.fetch(:from); to = hash.fetch(:to);`... instead of using `hash[:from]`?

Comment: This is a general question that has too different use cases to mention, just as there sometimes a need for avoiding silent failure by using `fetch` instead of `[]`, there is sometimes a need for using a fetch version of `values_at`.

Answer (score 126):

Use Hash's [`values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) method:

```
from, to, name = hash.values_at(:from, :to, :name)
```

This will return `nil` for any keys that don't exist in the hash.

Comment: This does not satisfy the OP's requirement.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Read the question by yourself.

Comment: There's no such method that will fetch multiple keys and railse exceptions for missing ones. One of the reasons may be - when an exception should be raised - when key is nonexistent (it may leave unassigned variables for other keys) or after fetching all keys? It's easy to add such check by yourself and I can't really see any reason why insist on raising exception here.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel "why insist on raising exception here" - because the keys MUST be present. "when an exception should be raised - when key is nonexistent (it may leave unassigned variables for other keys)" - yes, that would leave unassigned variable in case of a normal `fetch` too.

Comment: yes, but why not just use `raise MyException if hsh_values.include? nil`

Comment: @YoLudke, because in cases where the key doesn't exist at all that wouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 54):

Ruby 2.3 finally introduces the [`fetch_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-fetch_values) method for hashes that straightforwardly achieves this:

```
{a: 1, b: 2}.fetch_values(:a, :b)
# => [1, 2]
{a: 1, b: 2}.fetch_values(:a, :c)
# => KeyError: key not found: :c
```

Comment: So it does exists now, awesome 
This should be marked as the answer if possible because it's not the easiest to find.

Answer (score 5):

```
hash = {from: :foo, to: :bar, name: :buz}

[:from, :to, :name].map{|sym| hash.fetch(sym)}
# => [:foo, :bar, :buz]
[:frog, :to, :name].map{|sym| hash.fetch(sym)}
# => KeyError
```

Answer (score 3):

```
my_array = {from: 'Jamaica', to: 'St. Martin'}.values_at(:from, :to, :name)
my_array.keys.any? {|key| element.nil?} && raise || my_array
```

This will raise an error like you requested

```
 my_array = {from: 'Jamaica', to: 'St. Martin', name: 'George'}.values_at(:from, :to, :name)
 my_array.keys.any? {|key| element.nil?} && raise || my_array
```

This will return the array.

But OP asked for failing on a missing key...

```
class MissingKeyError < StandardError
end
my_hash = {from: 'Jamaica', to: 'St. Martin', name: 'George'}
my_array = my_hash.values_at(:from, :to, :name)
my_hash.keys.to_a == [:from, :to, :name] or raise MissingKeyError
my_hash = {from: 'Jamaica', to: 'St. Martin'}
my_array = my_hash.values_at(:from, :to, :name)
my_hash.keys.to_a == [:from, :to, :name] or raise MissingKeyError
```

Comment: ` my_array.any? {|element| element.nil?} && raise` would be incorrect because a key may exist with a `nil` value.

Comment: You are correct.  I checked the value rather than the key.  I will edit for key.

Comment: `keys.to_a == [:from, :to, :name]` is incorrect. The order will matter here, but the Hash keys have no particular order it should be at least `keys.to_a - [:from, :to, :name] == []`. Overall, it's just more effort than it's worth.

Comment: And if you do the subtraction and the key simply isn't there you still end up with an empty array, so that is not good either.  So matching an empty array will not mean that the key was necessarily there.  Missed it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing I would go for would be

```
from, to, name = [:from, :to, :name].map {|key| hash.fetch(key)}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `values_at`, you can use a `Hash` with a default value block:

```
hash=Hash.new {|h, k| raise KeyError.new("key not found: #{k.inspect}") }
# ... populate hash
from, to, name = hash.values_at(:from, :to, :name) # raises KeyError on missing key
```

Or, if you're so inclined, monkey-patch `Hash`

```
class ::Hash
  def fetch_all(*args)
    args.map {|key| fetch(key)}
  end
end
from, to, name = hash.fetch_all :from, :to, :name
```

Comment: How is this different from mine?

Comment: @sawa obviously, it assigns the results LOL :)

Answer (score 1):

You could initialise your hash with a default value of `KeyError` object. This will return an instance of KeyError if the key you are trying to fetch is not present. All you need to do then is check its (value's) class and raise it if its a KeyError.

```
hash = Hash.new(KeyError.new("key not found"))
```

Let's add some data to this hash

```
hash[:a], hash[:b], hash[:c] = "Foo", "Bar", nil
```

Finally look at the values and raise an error if key not found

```
hash.values_at(:a,:b,:c,:d).each {|v| raise v if v.class == KeyError}
```

This will raise an exception if and only if key is not present. It'll not complain in case you have a key with `nil` value.

Comment: I don't control how the Hash is created. So I'll have to recreate/copy just to use a "special" value as a marker of no-key.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching is an experimental feature in Ruby 2.7.

```rb
hash = { from: 'me', to: 'you', name: 'experimental ruby' }

hash in { from:, to:, name: }
```

See https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubyref/language/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 0):

I needed to have a hash being returned so I did a patch:

```rb
class Hash
  def multi_fetch(*keys)
    keys.map { |key| [key, fetch(key)] }.to_h
  end
end
```